# Covariance in C# compile error

Tags: c#

Why does the below code throw compile error? As per C# 4.0 Covariance should'nt such a conversion be allowed. **List employeeList = managerList;**

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Manager> managerList = new List<Manager>()
            {
                new Manager{ FirstName="ASFD", LastName="DSS", NoOfReportees=4},
                new Manager{ FirstName="rrr", LastName="dsasde", NoOfReportees=22}
            };
            List<Employee> employeeList = managerList;
        }
    }
    public class Employee
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
    public class Manager:Employee
    {
        public int NoOfReportees { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Covariance is allowed for interfaces only. `List<T>` is no interface. `IList<T>` is neither co-variant nor contra-variant because you have to read and write the elements.

Comment: `List<T>` is not what needs to be an interface.  Try making Employee implement IPerson

Comment: I think i have a wrong understanding on covariance. Let me see if i get some good tutorials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about it this way: If the assignment were allowed, you could do this:

```
List<Manager> managerList = new List<Manager>()
{
    new Manager{ FirstName="ASFD", LastName="DSS", NoOfReportees=4},
    new Manager{ FirstName="rrr", LastName="dsasde", NoOfReportees=22}
};
List<Employee> employeeList = managerList;
employeeList.Add(new Employee{ FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe"});
```

and now your managerList would contain an item that was not a `Manager`, violating the constraints of the list.

If it would suit your needs, you can, however, do this:

```
List<Employee> employeeList = new List<Employee>(managerList);
```

because it doesn't violate the original list.

Answer (score 4):

Neither `List` or `IList` are covariants.

Try this instead:

```
IEnumerable<Employee> employeeList = managerList
```

More information on MSDN: [Covariance and Contravariance (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`List<T>` is invariant. You need `IEnumerable<T>` which is `covariant`.

Refer to the explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966961/cannot-convert-from-listderivedclass-to-listbaseclass/16967217#16967217) by [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) explained so nicely with zoo analogy -

> A `List<Mammal>` cannot be converted to a `List<Animal>` because you
>   can put a lizard into a list of animals. A `List<Mammal>` cannot be
>   converted to a `List<Giraffe>` because there might be a tiger in the
>   list already.
>
> Therefore `List<T>` has to be invariant in T.
>
> However, `List<Mammal>` can be converted to `IEnumerable<Animal>` (as of
>   C# 4.0) because there is no method on `IEnumerable<Animal>` that adds
>   a lizard. `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant in T.

Answer (score 0):

Covariant interface must be declared explicitly using `out` keyword. If you are using .Net 4.5, there is `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` interface

```
IReadOnlyCollection<Employee> employeeList = managerList;
```

Noted that it is read-only, which is logical because we can read `Employee` from `List<Manager>` but we cannot add `Employee` to it.

Comment: Not just `IReadOnlyCollection<out T>`, there's even a [`IReadOnlyList<out T>` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh192385.aspx) which is covariant in its type arguement.