# WPF Datagrid.ItemsSource as List<Anything> and use on Linq

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, datagrid, itemssource

I'm searching more than 10 hours.

There are 10 classes and 1 datagrid in other window

```
datagrid1.ItemsSource = new List<class1>(); //+100 items in list
or
datagrid1.ItemsSource = new List<class2>(); //+100 items in list
or
datagrid1.ItemsSource = new List<class3>(); //+100 items in list
```

I need to convert and use the return items in Linq:

```
var items = datagrid1.ItemsSource as List<???>;
datagrid1.ItemsSource = items.Where(a => a.GetType().GetProperty("Name").GetValue(a, null).ToString().Contains("text"));
```

I'm using these. but not work

```
using System.Linq;

var items = datagrid1.ItemsSource as IList;
//Error CS1061  'IList' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'IList' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

var items = datagrid1.ItemsSource as List<dynamic>; // return null
var items = datagrid1.ItemsSource as List<object>; // return null
```

what things I should use instead ??? for support Linq?

Note: I wont use class1 or class2 or class3

Comment: `datagrid1.ItemsSource.Cast<object>().Where(...)`

Comment: Wow. this is my answer. very thanks.

Comment: but why ItemsSource as List<object> return null and cast<object> not return null ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linq extensions are available for generic enumerables (`IEnumerable<>`), `IList` is basically a `IEnumerable`, so the extensions will no be available for a `IList`.

Things like `datagrid1.ItemsSource as List<object>` returns `null` because a `List<DerivedClass>` isn't a `List<BaseClass>`, you can read more in this questions:

- [Convert List<DerivedClass> to List<BaseClass>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1817300/5178207)
- [Cannot convert from List<DerivedClass> to List<BaseClass>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16966961/5178207)

You can solve your problem calling [Cast<>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406(v=vs.100).aspx) extension (that is available for `IEnumerable`), this extension project the enumerable to a new `IEnumerable<>` casting each element to the specified generic type:

```
datagrid1.ItemsSource.Cast<object>().Where(...)
```

However, if you classes have a common class or interface and as `IEnumerable<>` is co-variant you try something like this:

```
interface INamedObject
{
    string Name { get; }
}

var items = datagrid1.ItemsSource as IEnumerable<INamedObject>;
datagrid1.ItemsSource = items.Where(a => a.Contains("text"));
```