# Type conversion for generic lists in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to figure out why the type conversion is not possible in the first case, but it is possible in the second one. Please, take a look at the code below:

```
var strList = new List<string>{"One", "Two", "Three"};
List<object> objList = (List<object>) strList; // <<<< why is not converted? - Case 1

IEnumerable<object> ienumList = strList; // <<<< why is converted?  - Case 2
```

Comment: Look at covariance and contravariance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966961/cannot-convert-from-listderivedclass-to-listbaseclass or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817300/convert-listderivedclass-to-listbaseclass.

Comment: If you still want to do s.th. similar to the cast to `List<object>`, you can use `OfType` od `Cast`

Answer (score 10):

While the [comment referring to covariance and contravariance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41806770/type-conversion-for-generic-lists-in-c-sharp#comment70801080_41806770) makes a good point about the underlying principle, I am going to answer in terms of the concrete effects in the presented case:

> ```
> List<object> objList = (List<object>) strList;
> ```

`objList` is writeable. It will allow you to do this:

```
objList.Add(new Object());
```

However, `objList` is still the same instance as `strList`. You have just added an instance of `System.Object` to a `List<string>`!

The compiler cannot allow that to happen. Thus, a `List<string>` cannot be cast to a `List<object>`.

In the second case, on the other hand, you retrieve an enumerable:

> ```
> IEnumerable<object> ienumList = strList;
> ```

There is no way to modify the resulting enumerable, as `IEnumerable<T>` does not provide any members that mutate the instance. Therefore, the type parameter `T` can be (and is) marked with the `out` keyword, which allows the presented typecast.

Answer (score 2):

Two major concepts play roles here: [Type Conversions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx) and [Generic Interfaces Variance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx). Where the variance is the leading one.

*Case 1:* In [`List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) class definition, we do not have variance on generic parameter. So we do not have any relations defined between `List<object>` and `List<string>`. They are invariant. Therefore both implicit and explicit type conversion are not possible.

*Case 2:* `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<out T>` which is covariant generic type, so `List<string>` can be implicitly cast to `IEnumerable<object>`

DETAILS:

Why the variance is not allowed for `List<T>`, but allowed for `IEnumerable<T>`?

The point of generics is to provide compile-time type safety.
Because `List<T>` is writable and if there wasn't a compile time check, we could write the following and have a run-time error:

```
List<string> stringList = new List<string>();
stringList.Add("some string"); // we are safe
List<object> objectList = stringList;
objectList.Add((new Object()); // Aargh! 
// we are trying to put an object to a list of strings!
```

So no unsafe variance for `List<T>`.

But `IEnumerable<out T>` is read-only. It does not provide a way to modify the referenced instance.

```
IEnumerable<object> objectList = new List<string>();
// we can't add a string to the objectList, 
// as `IEnumerable<out T>` is a read-only interface.
```

So a safe variance is possible.

Comment: Hi Kalitsov. I've taken the liberty to edit your answer with code markup so its a bit neater (as well as a few grammar corrections). For future reference to do this yourself you need to just surround the text you want marked as code with backticks (``) which will then mean that it will render it as code and not get confused by the `<>` which sometimes disappear without the code markup.

Comment: Thanks Chris! I was wandering how to do it.

Comment: The editor will also do this for you. If you highlight text in a paragraph (rather than full paragraphs) and hit the code button at the top (looks like `{ }`) then it will put in the backticks for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using framework 3.5 or higher, you can do this:

```
var strList = new List<string>{"One", "Two", "Three"};
List<object> objList = strList.Cast<object>().ToList();
```

You can take a look at @Hagashen Naidu it has a very good explanation for this case.

Comment: While this does offer a way to make that line of code word it doesn't actually answer the question of why the behaviour is as it is.

Comment: @Chris you are right. My bad. Nevertheless i´ll leave the answer as it as it may help someone.

Answer (score -1):

See the following for an explanation of co and contra-variance. Think it will give clarity on the issue you having:

http://tomasp.net/blog/variance-explained.aspx/

Comment: Link only answers are frowned upon here. Perhaps you can update your answer to include the relevant details from that page?