# Cannot pass List of subtype to a List of interface type (implemented by subtype) to a function in Visual Basic + Cannot be casted either

Tags: vb.net, interface, casting, subtype

I need to use only 1 function to process a list containing interface types so that I can reuse it for each subtype, but I also need to know the concrete type when handling the list-items higher up the function call stack:

`LoadAItems` calls `GetA` which calls `FilterItems`.

`FilterItems` needs to be generic so that `GetB` can also call and make use of it.

The problem is that trying to pass the list of subtypes to the general `FilterItems` method is not allowed:

"Cannot convert type 'List(Of AListItem)' to parameter type 'List(Of IListItem)'"

I tried converting each AListItem object in the list to IListItem and adding it to a new list but the problem is that the `FilterItems` function is supposed to remove elements from the list. If I remove elements from the new list then it will not affect the old list. I could convert it back but this is a lot of hassle just to be able to use the function.

I cannot just change everything to `List(Of IListItem)` because then I would need to always cast down the returned value from either `FilterItems` or `GetA` / `GetB` because `LoadAItems` / `LoadBItems` needs to know the concrete type.

I can see why casting down is bad, but why can't I cast up to the interface type the concrete types are implementing?

I have already tried:

```
FilterItems(CType(items, List(Of IListItem))
```

but this is not allowed:

"Value of type 'List(Of AListItem)' cannot be converted to 'List(Of IListItem)'"

Here is my code example:

```
Public Class AListItem
    Implements IListItem

    'Properties here

End Class

Public Class BListItem
    Implements IListItem

    'Properties here

End Class

Private Sub FilterItems(items As List(Of IListItem))
    'Remove items from the list that meet some condition
    items.RemoveAll(Function(item) ...)     

    'Does not matter what the items class type is
End Sub

Public Function GetA() As List(Of AListItem)
    Dim items As List(Of AListItem)

    items = CallDatabase()

    FilterItems(items) ' Does not allow!

    Return items
End Function

Public Function GetB() As List(Of BListItem)
    Dim items As List(Of BListItem)

    items = CallDatabase()

    FilterItems(items) ' Does not allow!

    Return items

End Function

Public Sub LoadAItems()
    Dim items As List(Of AListItem)

    items = GetA()

    'Do specific AListItem stuff (cannot use interface!)
End Sub

Public Sub LoadBItems()
    Dim items As List(Of BListItem)

    items = GetB()

    'Do specific BListItem stuff (cannot use interface!)
End Sub
```

Comment: See Eric Lippert's answer here: [Cannot convert from List<DerivedClass> to List<BaseClass>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16967217)

Comment: @VisualVincent No this is not a duplicate. I said specifically that an outside function needs to know the concrete type on purpose so I wouldn't get marked as duplicate...

Comment: @VisualVincent That solution does not work because `LoadAItems` would need to cast down the returned type from `IListItem` to the concrete type and the same problem would emerge

Comment: It is a duplicate for the same old reasons. `FilterItems` wants a `List(Of IListItem)`. Imagine that inside that function is does `items.Add(new AListItem())` and `iteams.Add(new BListItem())`. The list now contains a mixture of `AListItem` and `BListItem` objects, even though your original lists were only declared to allow one or the other of those types to be contained. Boom. Type safety gone.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Makes sense but is there a nicer way of making this function work for both types of IListItem without copying and pasting the entire function and only changing the parameter type?

Comment: How about making the function itself generic? `Private Sub FilterItems(Of T As IListItem)(items As List(Of T))` - Then you could call it like: `FilterItems(Of BListItem)(items)`

Comment: Yeah, that seems the simplest solution. Forgot you could do `Of T As IListItem` to add a constraint to the type of T

Comment: Glad I/we could help! Good luck with your project!

Comment: @VisualVincent Thank you, much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I correctly understand what you're trying to do you should be able to make the function itself generic:

```
Private Sub FilterItems(Of T As IListItem)(items As List(Of T))
```

`Of T As IListItem` adds a constraint that `T` must be, or inherit from `IListItem`.

Then you can call it like:

```
Public Function GetA() As List(Of AListItem)
    Dim items As List(Of AListItem)

    items = CallDatabase()

    FilterItems(Of AListItem)(items)

    Return items
End Function

Public Function GetB() As List(Of BListItem)
    Dim items As List(Of BListItem)

    items = CallDatabase()

    FilterItems(Of BListItem)(items)

    Return items
End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than having a function that takes and manipulates a `List(Of IListItem)`, instead create a function with a signature of:

```
Private Boolean IsGoodItem(IListItem)
```

With a hopefully straightforward conversion of your existing code within `FilterItems` to fit there. Then just change:

```
Public Function GetA() As List(Of AListItem)
    Dim items As List(Of AListItem)

    items = CallDatabase()

    FilterItems(items) ' Does not allow!

    Return items
End Function
```

To

```
Public Function GetA() As List(Of AListItem)
    Dim items As List(Of AListItem)

    items = CallDatabase()

    Return items.Where(IsGoodItem).ToList()
End Function
```

And you still get (a fair bit of) code reuse without stumbling over covariance/contravariance issues. (I think the compiler will be happy with inferring types for the `Where` or you may have to insert explicit type annotations here)