# Interface inheritance issue

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, interface

I have IBinaryNode interface and IRedBlackNode interface that inherits from IBinaryNode.

```
public interface IBinaryNode<T>
{
    public IBinaryNode<T>? Left  { get; set; }
    public IBinaryNode<T>? Right { get; set; }
    public T              Value { get; }

}

public interface IRedBlackNode<T> : IBinaryNode<T>
{
    IRedBlackNode<T>? Parent  { get; set; }
    bool              IsBlack { get; set; }
}
```

How can I use IRedBlackNode instead of IBinaryNode in the properties of the following class? I thought that if IRedBlackNode implements IBinaryNode then I can do it but I get type error that says that it must be IBinaryNode instead.

```
private class RedBlackNode : IRedBlackNode<T>
{
    public IRedBlackNode<T>? Parent  { get; set; }
    public IRedBlackNode<T>? Left    { get; set; }
    public IRedBlackNode<T>? Right   { get; set; }
    public bool              IsBlack { get; set; }
    public T                 Value   { get; }
}
```

Comment: If you are looking for solution (and not explanation) search for "curiously recurring template in C#". For explanation read classical https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966961/cannot-convert-from-listderivedclass-to-listbaseclass and it may be enough... or continue reading on (co-)variance and [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: [Covariant return types](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/49) may come in some future version of C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can't. Consider you have an instance of `RedBlackNode`, then it can be cast to `IBinaryNode<T>` and any other `IBinaryNode<T>` can be assigned to its `Right` property.

But, if you want to restrict class `RedBlackNode` to have only instances of `IRedBlackNode<T>` in its `Right` property, you can do it via explicit interface implementation:

```cs
public IRedBlackNode<T> Right { get; set; }

IBinaryNode<T> IBinaryNode<T>.Right
{
  get => Right;
  set => Right = (IRedBlackNode<T>)value;
}
```

P.S. If you only have getters on `Left` and `Right` it will work through covariance, but you have also setters

Answer (score 1):

I guess it will still work. Here's an example on how you could implement that. But further I don't see any problems here.

```
public interface IBinaryNode<T>
    where T : class
{
    public IBinaryNode<T>? Left { get; set; }
    public IBinaryNode<T>? Right { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; }

}

public interface IRedBlackNode<T> : IBinaryNode<T>
    where T : class
{
    IRedBlackNode<T>? Parent { get; set; }
    bool IsBlack { get; set; }
}

public class RedBlackNode<T> : IRedBlackNode<T>
    where T: class
{
    public IRedBlackNode<T>? Parent { get; set;}
    public IBinaryNode<T>? Right { get; set }
    public IBinaryNode<T>? Left { get; set ; }
    public bool IsBlack { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; }
}
```

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace: You're right. That was a dumb remark. Editited the anwer