# cast system.object to List<model> asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, object, model, dapper

I have a common dapper function to get `list<model>` using `QueryAsync` of `dapper`

the function looks like below

```
public async Task<object> QueryAsync(string spName, DynamicParameters p)
{
    return await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        object obj = new object();
        IList objectList = obj as IList;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connStr))
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                obj = (List<object>)await conn.QueryAsync<object>(sql: spName, param: p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Utils.Logger.Instance.LogException(ex);
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
        return obj;
    });
}
```

now I am calling this method from my businessLogic Layer like below

```
public async Task<List<GetTemplates>> GetDocTemplates(string TemplateName, int AccountId)
{
    _Parameters.Add("@SP_TemplateName", TemplateName, dbType: DbType.String, direction: ParameterDirection.Input);
    _Parameters.Add("@SP_AccountId", AccountId, dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Input);
    return (List<GetTemplates>)await _Dapper.QueryAsync("[dbo].[GetDocTemplates]", _Parameters);
}
```

but I am getting the following error.

> Unable to cast object of type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DocPro.DMS.BusinessEntities.Admin.GetTemplates]'.

I don't know what is wrong with the above code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert List<DerivedClass> to List<BaseClass>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817300/convert-listderivedclass-to-listbaseclass)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot convert from List<DerivedClass> to List<BaseClass>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16966961/11683)

Comment: No it does not answered as I have an object.

Comment: How does that make it different?

Comment: @TWMTV what you have here is a `List<object>` where each object is a `DapperRow`; now, `List<T>` isn't variant in the first place, so even if the objects were `GetTemplates` instances, you can't cast a `List<object>` to a `List<GetTemplates>` - but again, to emphasize: **there are no `GetTemplates` objects here**, so it *certainly* can't magic them into that shape. If you want a `List<GetTemplates>`: *tell Dapper that*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dapper creates the list here. If you want it to be a list of `GetTemplates`, then you're going to have to tell dapper about that, presumably by making the method generic and calling `_Dapper.QueryAsync<GetTemplates>(...)`. That said... honestly, this method isn't really adding anything except connection setup and logging - the `Task.Run` is unnecessary, the blind `catch` that swallows failure is actively dangerous, and `DynamicParameters` is the least preferred way of passing parameters to dapper. Suggestion:

```cs
public async Task<List<T>> QueryListAsync<T>(string spName, object parameters)
{
    using var conn = new SqlConnection(_connStr);
    try
    {
        return (await conn.QueryAsync<T>(sql: spName, param: parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure)).AsList();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Utils.Logger.Instance.LogException(ex);
        throw;
    }
}
...
public Task<List<GetTemplates>> GetDocTemplates(string TemplateName, int AccountId)
{
    return _Dapper.QueryListAsync<GetTemplates>("[dbo].[GetDocTemplates]", new {
        SP_TemplateName = TemplateName,
        SP_AccountId = AccountId
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked for me, but I have few questions it might sound stupid.

Comment: 1) Why DynamicParameters is least preferred?

Comment: I have few scenrio where I have a parameter with `ParameterDirection.Output` and `ParameterDirection.ReturnValue`

Comment: how can I use this?

Comment: help would be appreciated as I will do changes in my whole application as per your suggestion

Comment: @TWMTV for simple scenarios, the simple anon type option is simply more efficient; `DynamicParameters` is required for output / return-value scenarios, but you can still use that in the above by passing a `DynamicParameters` object as the `object parameters` arg - it'll still work; so here we allow more flexibility; use `DynamicParameters` when needed, and allow simple anon-types when not needed