How can I loop through the properties of a generic List with reflection?
I've written this method, but I get an issue when casting:

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[ConsoleApp7.RoomCategory]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.Object]'.

Method:
public class NetworkPacketSerializer
{
    public static void WriteArbitraryListPropertyToWriter(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, NetworkPacketWriter writer, object packet)
    {
        var collection = (List<object>)propertyInfo.GetValue(packet)!;
        writer.WriteInteger(collection.Count);

        var properties = collection
            .SelectMany(element =>
                element.GetType().GetProperties());
        
        foreach (var elementProperty in properties)
        {
            var x = elementProperty.GetValue(packet);
            // TODO; do something
        }
    }
}


A List<RoomCategory> is not a List<Object>. You can't just cast generics this way even if RoomCategory is surely an Object.

You might add the concrete type by making the method also generic and use RoomCategory as the genric parameter here.

If you could cast your list to List<Object>, you could also use collection.Add(someThingThatItNotARoomCategory). This is called co-variance and not allowed for lists (but for enumerables it is allowed). See this link for a deeper explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966961/cannot-convert-from-listderivedclass-to-listbaseclass

What is the actual goal here? Whenever you are using reflection you need to carefully consider if the safety tradeoffs are worth the advantage. If you just want to display all properties you might consider using a json serializer instead, that way the library deals with all the difficult reflection stuff.

You can cast the list to IEnumerable<object> since IEnumerable<T> is covariant. And you can replace .Count with .Count().
var collection = (IEnumerable<object>)propertyInfo.GetValue(packet)!;
writer.WriteInteger(collection.Count());


Casting to something to something generic here when i'm actual not interesting in the concrete type, hence the use of object, should we not rather just cast then to something non-generic like IList?

But you cannot use linq with non-generic types.

Had not the feeling that its really needed here but yeah i don't know whats happening behind the // TODO; do something comment.

Yes, we don't know that, so I think we should maintain the logic of the OP.

You can use an IList instead of a list of object:
public class NetworkPacketSerializer
{
    public static void WriteArbitraryListPropertyToWriter(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, NetworkPacketWriter writer, object packet)
    {
        var elements = (IList)propertyInfo.GetValue(packet)!;
        writer.WriteInteger(elements.Count);

        foreach (var element in elements)
        {
            var properties = element.GetType().GetProperties();
            foreach (var elementProperty in properties)
            {
                var value = elementProperty.GetValue(element);
                // TODO; do something
            }
        }
    }
}

BTW, I fixed your logic, since in the original code the SelectMany seems to be erroneous: it's loop on all properties of all elements of the list without keeping a reference to the elements.
