# Python : pyright : Self@T is not compatible with T

Tags: python-typing, pyright

I am using pyright in my project to have some type-safety and I stub upon a type problem that I don't understand. It is really easy to fix (using `covariant=True` in the TypeVar) but I don't even understand why is it a problem itself.

Here is an example of my problem:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Callable, Generic


class A:
    ...

# Any subclass of A or A that is needed in a Generic
AT = TypeVar("AT", bound=A)

# Generic T where T is a subclass of A or A
class B(Generic[AT]):
    ...

# Decorator that converts a method of subclass of A (or A) to an instance of B[AT]
def to_b_instance(method: Callable[[AT], Any]) -> B[AT]:
    return B()

# Decorator that takes a predicate B[AT]->bool and an instance of B[AT]
def check_b_instance(predicate: Callable[[B[AT]], bool]) -> Callable[[B[AT]], Any]:
    def inner(b: B[AT]):
        ...
    return inner

# A predicate that can check B[SubA]'s instances 
def my_predicate(b: B["SubA"]):
    return True

class SubA(A):
    @check_b_instance(my_predicate)  # <- The problem is displayed here (full error bellow)
    @to_b_instance
    def methode(self):
        pass
```

```
Argument of type "B[Self@SubA]" cannot be assigned to parameter of type "B[SubA]"
  "B[Self@SubA]" is incompatible with "B[SubA]"
    TypeVar "AT@B" is invariant
      Type "Self@SubA" cannot be assigned to type "SubA" Pyright(reportGeneralTypeIssues)
```

Firstly **this error is not raised by mypy**, making me confident that this is a bug on pyright side.

I know that I can fix the problem by changing the AT TypeVar `TypeVar("AT", bound=A, covariant=True)` but I just don't understand how `Self@SubA` is different than `SubA` and what rule forces me to do so.

By the way, explicitly typing the `self` parameter with `SubA` seems to fix the problem too, without adding any additional error. I really don't get it.

```py
# AT is not covariant

class SubA(A):
    @check_b_instance(my_predicate)
    @to_b_instance
    def methode(self: "SubA"):  # <- No error anymore
        pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Co-/contra-/in-)variance is related to how generics and subclasses interact. In your specific case, `Self@SubA` isn't necessarily `SubA` iself, but might be any subclass of it. Your predicate, however, only expects its argument to be of type `B[SubA]`. Covariance cannot be assumed by default - for instance, if `B` was `List` and `SubA` was `object`, `my_predicate(b: List[object])` would've been allowed to call both `b.append(123)` and `b.append("Hello")`, since all of those are `objects`. However, while `int` is a subclass of `object`, `List[int]` can not be treated as a subclass of `List[object]` for this regard, since `b.append("Hello")` would be invalid for it.

I haven't met any particularly outstanding introduction into generics and variance, but you may check out the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)?useskin=vector) or [some other StackOverflow questions about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508529/covariant-generic-parameter).

**EDIT:** (To address the question from the comment):
Consider that I add the following code to yours:

```py
class Foo(SubA):
    pass

foo = Foo()

foo.methode()
```

Now the call to `methode` receives `foo` as its `self` argument, whose type is `Foo`, not `SubA`. This is fine, because OOP allow a subclass to be used whereever the parent class is expected. However, now the `Self` type, when (explicitly or implicitly) used in the type signature of `methode` is resolved to `Foo` for this particular call. This `Self` is referred to by pyright as `Self@SubA`, becuase it is bound to `SubA`. But, once again, it is currently `Foo`. Now, it passes through the code added by the decorators until the obtained value of type `B[Foo]` is attempted to be passed to `my_decorator`. `B[Foo]` is not considered a subclass of `B[SubA]`, unless B is covariant on its generic parameter. So the invocation is invalid due to an incomatible type.

You may argue that there are no subclasses to `SubA` in your code, but neither are there any rules preventing those from being introduced, so the type checker cannot make the assumption that the only type matching `Self@SubA` would be `SubA` itself.

When you explicitly annotate `methode`'s `self` argument to be `SubA`, everything works because now `self` is regarded as an instance of `SubA` even when it belongs to a deeper subclass. This results in `B[SubA]` being the type of the parameter passed to `my_decorator`, which is the expected one, regardless of `B`'s variance.

Comment: I already know about the `list[object]` / `list[int]` problem. I did not quite understand why "Self@SubA isn't necessarily SubA iself". `Self@T` is just a way to note the Self parameter inside a class T. So, yes, `Self@SubA` will be a `SubA` instance.

As mypy does not complain about this, I do think that pyright is wrong here.

Comment: @CallMePixelMan yes, but is `x` is an instance of `SubA`, it only means that `type(x)` is a subclass of `SubA`, not `SubA` itself. That's exactly the reason why the type is spelled as `Self@SubA` and not `SubA`

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get it. How `Self@SubA` can be different than `SubA` directly? Self is just a way to refer to the method's direct class instance, and was created to avoid problems when subclassing a class than had a method that returned self.

Comment: @CallMePixelMan see the update to the answer